# Would high-g travel require medical assistance?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space-travel, medical

I was reading about the "Osteo-X" and "the juice" from *The Expanse* series, and it got me wondering about my own setting. Would transportation services, say, from the moon and back, require medical followup?

### More Specific Context

Let's say Alex is a middle-aged, Earth-born man of average health. He is contracted by a lunar mining company for 6 months, and at the end of his stint, returns home. Would Alex need to take blood thinners to prevent blood clots from rapid deceleration?

Comment: This format works better with a single question per question -- and one of the *four* in this one is too open-ended ("is there any medical component that I'm missing?") for this forum to answer at all.  I'd suggest you start with the G force question, as that's well researched, and try to phrase it as a single question.  You can [edit] your question easily.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Thanks for the heads up, I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: I do believe that NASA might object you your statement of "What would the g-force threshold be? I don't think there's any real research on this"

Comment: @MarvinKitfox I probably just didn't look hard enough, I would assume NASA has put humans through the wringer just to record data

Comment: @RyanKim look to this discussion for some excellent references regarding human g-force health studies: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6154/maximum-survivable-long-term-g-forces

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions. There's the effect of living for 6 months at low-g (one the moon at 1/6th g), and there's the effect of travelling at high-g.  One to a customer please.

Comment: @puppetsock I see, lemme edit my question then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, there is not a lot of research on the effects of acceleration, and what is known is based almost entirely on subjects (pilots) who were chosen to have an unusually low risk of cardiovascular problems.  The same is true for the other medical risks specifically associated with space travel (mainly due to prolonged weightlessness and isolation in confined environments).

We know a fair bit about the likely risks just from the physics; if you increase the pressure in a garden hose, the risk of it bursting will increase until it reaches 100%, and the maximum pressure is determined by the hose's weakest point.  The more Gs you expose someone to, the greater the chance they will burst a blood vessel or their heart will give out.  So you would certainly want to have a first-aid setup to handle that, and it would factor into insurance costs etc.  I guess blood thinners might be recommended as a preventative measure for some people.

However, if someone survives a high-G maneuver without incident, there's little reason to expect long-term damage that would require follow-up; it's like doing an excessive workout on a treadmill.

Blood clots are a risk when blood in your extremities doesn't circulate properly for sustained periods.  That wouldn't be an issue for maneuvers lasting a couple of minutes, but it certainly could be if you were at >1G for hours, like in *The Expanse* (no human has experienced those conditions in real life).

Suppose that the pressure head in your feet is 2m when you're standing up, and 20cm when you're lying down; that suggests that even 10G of acceleration wouldn't necessarily exceed what your blood vessels can handle (the ones in your legs, anyway), provided you were "lying down" and properly supported.  But if you were lying on your keys or something, you would get some serious bruising and possibly blood clots as a result.  And your heart and lungs would be working much harder than normal.

You didn't mention ionizing radiation – the risks from that are fairly well known, and affect people more or less uniformly as far as I know.  Assuming you can avoid acute radiation sickness (e.g. from being exposed to solar flares in a spacecraft), your risk of cancer goes up in proportion to how much radiation you're exposed to, and there's no medical intervention that will change that.  An underground base on the Moon or Mars could be shielded, but on a spacecraft you're slowly collecting genetic damage with each hour that passes.  For this reason, it will probably never be recommended for pregnant women, and people with plans to have children would probably be advised to freeze their gametes before going on long space trips.

Comment: Hm, I had been considering the risk of ionizing radiation, though I always thought there was some sort of workaround? Is modern spacecraft radiation shielding insufficient to facilitate safe travel?

Comment: @RyanKim It's safe enough that, over a particular astronaut's career, they have no more than a certain chance of developing complications. But that may or may not be rated safe enough for workers who spend more time in space over a longer period of their lives, or whose jobs take them to different places.

Comment: @Cadence I see, that would actually make for some good storytelling elements, i.e. space miners demanding company-paid oncological care and gamete freezing.

Answer (score -1):

So the person with the highest flight altitude record (Jim Lovell, Apollo 13) was 42 years old at the time of flight (his two fellow astronauts were junior to him by a few years) and he is currently alive and well at 92 as of writing.

The highest G-Force experiences by NASA space flight was 4 Gs during the Apollo days though most Astronauts experienced 3 Gs at launch.   There are also two types of G forces:  Verticle (motion is parallel to the spine) and Horizontal (Motion is perpendicular to the spine) and the former is less tolerable than the later.   Humans can only handle about -3 Gs of Verticle to a high of 9 Gs of verticle with proper training and a modern G suit, though the average human is more likely to experience a (very low) negaive verticle Gs.  Negative Horizontal Gs will create a feeling of weigthlessness and you can best experience this when sitting in the back of a roller Coaster's train (the further back the better the "air time" which is the roller coaster enthusiests term for this effect.  It's that time when you feel like you're about to fly out of your seat when you go over a hill).   Horizontal Gs are require either a great amount of force or a great amount of time to sustain damaging effects.  Untrained, humans can safely tolerate a sustained 6 gs of Horizontal Gs force for 10 minutes.   The highest ever g-force ever recoreded in the Horizontal and survived was a very sudden and brief 214 gs during a stock car crash.

This difference is why your astronauts are strapped into the shuttle facing the sky... the 3 gs of launch force is now in a Horizontal motion and not a verticle motion.   Since a shuttle lanunch takes all of 8 minutes from ground to Low Earth Orbit, this shouldn't be an issue, even before we factor in all that gear they wear to keep them safe from this.

High Gs were never much of a thing once in spaces flight and only come up in launch and landing.  The reason for high Gs in landing is that there has yet been a space craft capable of a controlled landing and all manned space craft are best described as not flying, but "falling with style" and sometimes not even with style.   All Russian spacecraft and the first three U.S. space craft were capsules that basically fell back to the Earth and deployed parachutes to slow the fall into a survivable landing.   The Space Shuttle's Orbitor (the part of the space shuttle that looks like an airplane... the entire stack, including the Oribitor, the External Tank (that big orange thingy) and the twin Solid Rocket Boosers (the two white rocket parts) is referted to as the Space Shuttle).  Would return via gliding but had no ability to actually fly or adjust its speed or altitude beyond rudimentery decreases.   For safety, it was entering without fuel and was mostly computer guided in it's known adjustments.

Comment: This isn't very clear and doesn't really address the main thrust of the question.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer contains false data. "The highest G-Force experiences by NASA space flight was 4 Gs during the Apollo days".. Apollo 16 experienced 7.19g during reentry. **nominal, planned** reentry for Apollo was 6.3-6.9g ... ref: https://history.nasa.gov/SP-368/s2ch5.htm